# Google Drive upload file to example@gmail.com in Python

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api

Can anyone please tell me how to upload a file to my gmail account using python? I can't figure out how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

https://developers.google.com/live/shows/ahNzfmdvb2dsZS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzcg4LEgVFdmVudBiVlJoDDA

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive has an API that allows read/write access. You'll have to [authorize](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth) first.

[Overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

[Try-it (click Python tab)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it)